# How to delete a large number of records in MS Access, with VBA

Tags: ms-access-2010

One can easily delete many records from a MS Access DB table with a standard SQL DELETE command in the query window. 
However, when trying to execute that same command thru VBA, the app can/does choke when there are more than 20,000 records to delete.

I temporarily worked around the issue by running a loop and doing the DELETE jobe in smaller 'chunks', 
but I would like to know if there is a better way to handle this situation.
BTW, No, there is not another option for a more robust Database. This job is specced out for MS Access, period.

Answer (score 3):

You want ADO DB's `adAsyncExecute` to run your command asynchronously.

- Open your Access DB
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor
- From the `Tools` menu choose `References...`
- Add "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library" or whatever the latest version is

Then use code like the following:

```vbs
Dim sSql As String
Dim oCmd As ADODB.Command
sSql = "DELETE FROM TableName WHERE 1=1"
Set oCmd = New ADODB.Command
With oCmd
    .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = sSql
    .Execute adAsyncExecute
End With
```

**Edit:** Another option is to run the query in another form, just make sure the form isn't always on top, you can execute the query in the other form's load event.